# How can I login to site after URLConnection in Java?

Tags: java, url, cookies, authentication, urlconnection

How can I login to site after URLConnection in Java?

I'm doing URLConnection in this way:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
while (scanner.hasNext())
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
```

After connection i am receiving a welcome page, but i need "https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates".

- How can i login to my linkedin?
- How can receive a cookie?
- How can i send a cookie at next time? Can i send a cookie taken on my web browser?

**UPD:**
To take a cookie i'm using:

```
String cookie = urlConnection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie").get(0);
```

Comment: It's likely that LinkedIn will do its best to prevent what you are trying to do, and it may even say you must not do that in their terms, but I may be wrong here. In any case you need to go through the login page and need make a request to that page first. Investigate what your browser does and try to replay it. Read on Java's cookie manager here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I receive a cookie?

```
        connection.getHeaderFields();
```

Look through the output and look for the Set-Cookie header. After that there should be  GUID = .... That is your cookie.

After you've gotten the cookie, and stored it somewhere, the easiest way to "send" the website your cookie is using this:

```
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
```

cookie being a string.

Use a HTTTP Listener addon on your browser and connect to the website that way.
https://gyazo.com/789db4f2ccb90d97516663de4ad1c6fa

With this knowledge, you can just repeat what the browser did in your app. Like:

```
 connection.setRequestProperty(*Request header*,*value of request header*);
```

You can't send your browser's cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You need to login via [oauth](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication).  You can use almost any http library to connect, but I would recommend using [scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) to authenticate, as it has built in bindings for Linked In.